# How to remove empty rows from text file

Tags: bash, text-files, newline

I have a text file like this [End-of-Line-characters in square brackets].

Clearly somethings wrong here and I want to remove the empty lines. How can I do this?

I would prefer a bash solution, but also others are welcome.

```
717016|2026493|88650639|Agridex|Carrier|NR||V/V||NR|||1||NR||NR||NR[CR][LF]
717016|2026493|88650639|Agridex|Carrier|NR||V/V||NR|||1||NR||NR||NR[CR][LF]
717018|2026494|67685|Sulfinyl bis(methane)|Carrier|NR||NR||NR|||NR||NR||NR||10% OF CARRIER SOLUTION[CR]
[CR][LF]
[CR][LF]
717019|2026494|57556|1,2-Propanediol|Carrier|NR||NR||NR|||NR||NR||NR||40% OF CARRIER SOLUTION[CR][LF]
717016|2026493|88650639|Agridex|Carrier|NR||V/V||NR|||1||NR||NR||NR[CR][LF]
```

This did not work (dont know why..):

```
sed -i '/^$/d' file.txt
```

**UPDATE**
My desired output is

```
717016|2026493|88650639|Agridex|Carrier|NR||V/V||NR|||1||NR||NR||NR[CR][LF]
717016|2026493|88650639|Agridex|Carrier|NR||V/V||NR|||1||NR||NR||NR[CR][LF]
717018|2026494|67685|Sulfinyl bis(methane)|Carrier|NR||NR||NR|||NR||NR||NR||10% OF CARRIER SOLUTION[CR][LF]
717019|2026494|57556|1,2-Propanediol|Carrier|NR||NR||NR|||NR||NR||NR||40% OF CARRIER SOLUTION[CR][LF]
717016|2026493|88650639|Agridex|Carrier|NR||V/V||NR|||1||NR||NR||NR[CR][LF]
```

So the third line ends with [CR][LF] and lines 4 + 5 are removed.

Comment: I am on Linux, but it is likely that the file is from windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\r` to represent LF:

```
sed '/^\r$/d' file
```

Or, run `dos2unix` on the file to get rid of the linefeeds.

Comment: I believe this works with gnu sed only since sed on OSX doesn't like this command.

Comment: Thanks, this removes one of the two [CR][LF] lines, however in the line before the empty lines I have only a [CR]. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sed command:

```
sed -i.bak '/^ *'$'\r''*$/d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ offer (you mention *others are welcome*!):

[image: SO17967892 example]

*Edit for clarification to question:*

First replace double [CR] with single, then Edit, Line Operations, Remove Empty Lines.

Answer (score 0):

try:

`grep "|" textfile.txt > output.txt`